# Need my webpage to live update without being refreshed so each user can see what other users have done. django, javascript

Tags: html, css

The idea is that there will be a bunch of users (10 in my case) simultaneously using the web page. They will be bidding against each other in real time which means they need to see the other bidders' bids when they happen.

What is the best approach to doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: make your website dynamic, you can use AnguarJS for "live update"

Comment: Just to clarify, if one user makes a bid, the other users will see the website update with that user's bid as well?

Comment: yea of course, that's what dynamic web sites do

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: I have a bare bones auction up and running using angularjs. However, when other users go to the website, they aren't in the same session (probably the wrong term, but you get the idea). They load an independent version. What am I missing?